# Left join vs inner join ksqldb

Tags: sql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, ksqldb

I am very new to kafka streams and ksqlDB. I am trying to join two streams using ksqldb.

```
WITH(KAFKA_TOPIC='joined_stream',
    VALUE_FORMAT='JSON',
    PARTITIONS = 2) AS
SELECT a.id,
       a.timestamp_init,
       a.status,
       a.mobilenumber,
       b.SubType
FROM sample_1 a LEFT JOIN sample_2 b
WITHIN 5 MINUTES
ON a.id = b.id;
```

When the data is produced in the first stream, the new streams gets new record with second record as null. After the right table gets the data new record is produced in the stream with the joined data, thus there comes two records.
I want to get only one record. If the matching record does not come in the right stream after 5 mins then it should produce null else it should join and produce to the new stream. Inner join might loss some record that from the left stream if there is no matching record is produced in the right stream, which I cannot afford.
Thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: What constraint of the system consuming the joined topic prevents you from just doing the left join you describe? It will be eventually consistent.

Comment: So, eventually it would be consistent. Is there a way I can know how long will it take to be consistent? I would be consuming from the output topic in almost realtime and my records per second is about 6000. Will that be handled by ksqldb?

Comment: It will take, at most, 5 minutes to be consistent, as that's the join window you specified. So if a message `A` comes on the left stream, and a corresponding message hasn't come on the right stream, then the join will produce a message `[A,null]` (as you observed). However if a message `a` on the right stream with the same key comes in within 5 mins the join will produce message `[A,a]` and your consumer's view of the world will become consistent. If no message with the same key comes in within 5 mins the consumer's view of the world will remain as `[A, null]`.

Comment: re whether ksqldb will be able to handle 6000 message per second - this depends on how well resourced the nodes on your ksqlDB cluster are. It also depends whether the topic is partitioned i.e that load can be split between nodes in the cluster.